# Basics of webscraping

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to get the prices of all the models of Maruti Alto using Web scraping. I am trying the code to get the data but i am not able to get it.

```
Sub Basics_Of_Web_Macro()
    Dim myIE As Object
    Dim myIEDoc As Object
 
    'Start Internet Explorer
    Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 
    'if you want to see the window set this to True
    myIE.Visible = False
 
    'Now we open the page we'd like to use as a source for information
    myIE.navigate "https://www.marutisuzuki.com/channels/arena/price-list/alto-price-in-mumbai-in-maharashtra"
 
    'We wait for the Explorer to actually open the page and finish loading
    While myIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
 
    'Now lets read the HTML content of the page
    Set myIEDoc = myIE.document
 
    'Time to grab the information we want
 
    Range("A1") = myIEDoc.Title
    'Then we'll get something from teh inner page content by using the ID
        
    Range("B1") = myIEDoc.Class("priceInfo clearfix")    
End Sub
```

Comment: *"i am not able to get it"* is no useful error description. You need to tell where you got errors and which, or where you got stuck. If you don't tell us where exactly your issues and difficulties are we cannot help you. Furthermore you need to ask a question. See [ask] and [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: You probably need something like `myIEDoc.getElementsByClassName("priceInfo clearfix")`, which is a collection of elements whose class name is "priceInfo clearfix". From this collection you can then get the element you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XHR:**

You could use xmlhttp request and avoid browser. Loop the nodeList returned by collecting the classname `cols`. Start new row every 5 element and reset column to 1 for output. Thus creating tabular format for output from list format of nodeList/

VBE> Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetPrices()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.marutisuzuki.com/channels/arena/price-list/alto-price-in-mumbai-in-maharashtra", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim listings As Object, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, results()
    Set listings = html.querySelectorAll(".cols")
    ReDim results(1 To (listings.Length - 2) / 4, 1 To 4)
    r = 1: c = 1
    For i = 0 To listings.Length - 2
        If i Mod 4 = 0 And i > 0 Then r = r + 1: c = 1
        results(r, c) = listings.item(i).innerText
        c = c + 1
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

---

**Internet Explorer:**

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetPrices()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.marutisuzuki.com/channels/arena/price-list/alto-price-in-mumbai-in-maharashtra"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim listings As Object, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, results()
        Set listings = .document.querySelectorAll(".cols")
        ReDim results(1 To (listings.Length - 2) / 4, 1 To 4)
        r = 1: c = 1
        For i = 0 To listings.Length - 2
            If i Mod 4 = 0 And i > 0 Then r = r + 1: c = 1
            results(r, c) = listings.item(i).innerText
            c = c + 1
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```